# Delete File after successful persist to MongoDB in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration flow that reads a csv file from a directory, splits the lines, then processes each line and extracts 2 objects from each line. These two objects are then send to two seperate `int-mongodb:outbound-channel-adapter`. I want to delete the incoming file after all of the lines have been processed and persisted. I have seen example of using the Transaction Manager to do this with the inbound adapter, but nothing with the outbound adapter.  Is there a way to do this?

My config looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mongodb http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mongodb/spring-integration-mongodb.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:int-mongodb="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mongodb"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo">

    <int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="50"/>

    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesInChannel"
                                      directory="file:${file.ingest.directory}"
                                      auto-create-directory="true">
        <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="100">
        </int:poller>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10" queue-capacity="50" />
    <int:channel id="executorChannel">
        <int:queue capacity="50"/>
    </int:channel>

    <int:splitter input-channel="filesInChannel" output-channel="executorChannel"
                  expression="T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).lineIterator(payload)"/>

    <int:service-activator id="lineParserActivator"  ref="lineParser" method="parseLine"
                           input-channel="executorChannel" output-channel="lineChannel">
        <int:poller task-executor="executor" fixed-delay="500">
        </int:poller>
    </int:service-activator>

    <bean name="lineParser" class="com.xxx.LineParser"/>

    <int:channel id="lineChannel">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="lineMongoOutput">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="actionMongoOutput">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>

    <int:transformer input-channel="lineChannel" output-channel="lineMongoOutput">
        <bean id="lineTransformer" class="com.xxx.transformer.LineTransformer"></bean>  
    </int:transformer>
    <int:transformer input-channel="lineChannel" output-channel="actionMongoOutput">
        <bean id="actionTransformer" class="com.xxx.transformer.ActionTransformer"></bean>  
    </int:transformer>

    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="${mongo.db.name}" password="${mongo.db.pass}" username="${mongo.db.user}" port="${mongo.db.port}" host="${mongo.db.host}"/>

    <int-mongodb:outbound-channel-adapter id="lineMongoOutput"
                                          collection-name="full"
                                          mongodb-factory="mongoDbFactory" />
    <int-mongodb:outbound-channel-adapter id="actionMongoOutput"
                                          collection-name="action"
                                          mongodb-factory="mongoDbFactory" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do it on the outbound adapter because you don't know when you're "done". Given you are asynchronously handing off to the downstream flow (via executors and queue channels), you can't do it on the inbound adapter either, because the poller thread will return to the adapter as soon as all the splits are sent.

Aside from that, I see some issues in your flow:

You seem to have an excessive amount of thread handoffs - you really don't need queue channels in the downstream flow because your executions are controlled by the exec. channel.

It is quite unusual to make every channel a QueueChannel.

Finally, you have 2 transformers subscribed to the same channel.

Do you realize that messages sent to `lineChannel` will alternate round-robin style.

Perhaps that is your intent, given your description, but it seems a little brittle to me; I would prefer to see the different data types going to different channels.

If you avoid using queue channels, and use gateways within your service activator to send out the data to the mongo adapters, your service activator would know when it is complete and be able to remove the file at that time.

**EDIT:**

Here is one solution (it writes to logs rather than mongo, but you should get the idea)...

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="/tmp/foo" channel="toSplitter">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000">
        <int:transactional synchronization-factory="sf" transaction-manager="ptxMgr" />
    </int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="sf">
    <int:after-commit expression="payload.delete()" />
    <int:after-rollback expression="payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('/tmp/bad/' + payload.name))" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<bean id="ptxMgr" class="org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager" />

<int:splitter input-channel="toSplitter" output-channel="processChannel">
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.splitter.FileSplitter" />
</int:splitter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="processChannel">
    <bean class="foo.Foo">
        <constructor-arg ref="gate" />
    </bean>
</int:service-activator>

<int:gateway id="gate" service-interface="foo.Foo$Gate">
    <int:method name="toLine" request-channel="toLine" />
    <int:method name="toAction" request-channel="toAction" />
</int:gateway>

<int:channel id="toLine" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="toLine" expression="'LINE:' + payload" level="WARN"/>

<int:channel id="toAction" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="toAction" expression="'ACTION:' + payload" level="WARN"/>
```

.

```
public class Foo {

    private final Gate gateway;

    public Foo(Gate gateway) {
        this.gateway = gateway;
    }

    public void parse(String payload) {
        String[] split = payload.split(",");
        if (split.length != 2) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Bad row size: " + split.length);
        }
        this.gateway.toLine(split[0]);
        this.gateway.toAction(split[1]);
    }

    public interface Gate {

        void toLine(String line);

        void toAction(String action);
    }

}
```

.

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class FooTests {

    @Test
    public void testGood() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("/tmp/foo/x.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write("foo,bar".getBytes());
        fos.close();
        int n = 0;
        while(n++ < 100 && file.exists()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        assertFalse(file.exists());
    }

    @Test
    public void testBad() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("/tmp/foo/y.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write("foo".getBytes());
        fos.close();
        int n = 0;
        while(n++ < 100 && file.exists()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        assertFalse(file.exists());
        file = new File("/tmp/bad/y.txt");
        assertTrue(file.exists());
        file.delete();
    }

}
```

Add a task executor to the `<poller/>` to process multiple files concurrently. Add a router as needed.

Comment: ah, yes, i'm new to SI. Thanks for the tips. Basically, I want to process each line and output two different objects that each get persisted to the DB.  Is there a better way to do that processing without subscribing to the channel with two transformers?

Comment: See the last paragraph in my answer; you can use [Messaging Gateways](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) to invoke each transformer (and the flow downstream thereof). You can also keep track of the progress and remove the file when complete.

Comment: Gary, are there any examples of doing this?  I've having a hard time following how to do this in the documentation. The Cafe sample seems close, but it doesn't seem to worry about the transaction.  I don't know if I need to chain things either or how/when a transaction would end.  There just doesn't seem to be any doco on using gateways with service activators.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you need to process the lines in parallel or can you process all the lines in each file on one thread - the latter is much simpler because you can simply use a pseudo transaction on the inbound poller (and just use direct channels throughout). If the former, it can be done, but it's a bit more complicated. Before I put together an example, I need to know the requirements.

Comment: Each file (and all the lines there in) can be on one thread.  We could have separate file types that would be parsed by different transformers, so i was thinking of using a router on the inbound as well to split them to different paths based on file extension.  But each could be processed in their own thread.  Then once the each file has been process, we can delete it/move it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is great Gary!  Thanks so much for your time and effort!